# converting pdf to ipad supported formatI

Tags: iphone, ipad

i've a problem in converting pdf to any other formats which is supported by ipad.I tried svg and epub but everything has some drawback. Can any one suggest me software which is comaptable for ipad and memory aspects?

Thank you all.....

hi every one finally i got solution for this question.directly we can read and display pdf.there is no issue with that.
thank you all.

Comment: why are you trying to convert it?

Comment: pdf format  supports in ipad but while zooming images are not displaying well.so we need to convert pdf formate to other format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at UIWebView. I have read that it can be used to view PDFs, though there are postings about performance issues. You might also look at the Quartz 2D Programming Guide's section on opening and viewing PDFs.

And, finally, there's the [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. (Which requires iOS 4.0 or later.)

I know were looking for non-PDF formats that are supported on iPad. But it looks like PDF is supported on the iPad - and with the advent of iOS 4.2 very soon, even this Zooming PDFViewer should work on iPad.